# Swift picker array error

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, picker

```
var pickerData: [[String]] = [String]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Connect data:
    self.gothramPicker.delegate = self
    self.gothramPicker.dataSource = self
    pickerData = [
            [["A"],["i","ii","iii"]],
            [["B"],["iv","v","vi","vii"]]
    ]"
```

getting error of Contextual type 'String' cannot be used with array literal.  my picker has two sections and each item if selected in the first picker has its own subdivisions to select from the second picker.

I want to use Array in Array and each main array has subarrays of different list. When I select first array in the picker it should show only the subitems of the particular Array item. For which when I add the double Brackets, I am getting the error. Also please let me know any error in the code

Comment: You might want to tag the language so the right people can find this question

Comment: Anybody can support?

Comment: Awaiting for the help

Comment: I added the tag for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is it about the error on the first line (defining `pickerData`)?

Answer (score 0):

@sureshtrb , I am not posting answer because you don't asked question here. Frankly, you are troubling in Syntax understanding only.
 You were declaring picketData of type Array([]) that contains array of string[[String]], and by putting ["A"] in place of string, you are adding an array ["A"] in  place of String "A".

As per your real problem, I suggest you to go with 2 diff array or use dictionary.

The below code compiles.

```
    var pickerData: [[String]] = [[String]]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerData = [
                  ["A","i","ii","iii"],
                  ["B","iv","v","vi","vii"]
                 ]
    }
```

Comment: Based on your suggestion, the picker will show all the second Array list for for each first array item. My requirement is first array item will have some specific list of items to select and the second may have other list. Hope my requirement is clear